# useState in react-native doesn't works on android via EXPO

Tags: typescript, react-native, socket.io, expo, use-state

I'm trying to make an user join a room in socket.io.
The event sent from react-native client is :

```js
export default function App() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [room, setRoom] = useState('')
  const [showChat, setShowChat] = useState(false)

  const joinRoom = () => {
    if (username === '' || room === '') return
    socket.emit('join:room', {room: room, user: username, test: 'test'})
    await setShowChat(true)
  }
```

On web browser, it's working fine, and my node.js server receieve

```js
{ room: '2894', user: '5656', test: 'test' }
```

But on my phone with explo, I correctly connect to web socket, but when I send the 'join:room' event, the server recieve this :

```js
{ test: 'test', user: undefined }
```

For info, the useState() are updated when user change the TextInput:

```js
<TextInput
 style={styles.input}
 placeholder='Room...'
 onChange={async (event) => {
  await setRoom(event.target.value)
}}/>
```

and the joinRoom() method is called when TouchableOpacity is pressed.

```js
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={joinRoom} style={styles.button}>
     <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Join a room </Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like a strange use of state on your text input.

```
<TextInput
 style={styles.input}
 placeholder='Room...'
 onChange={async (event) => {
  await setRoom(event.target.value)
}}/>
```

If you're trying to get the state of the text input in your react app through a state variable, I would have expected it to look something like this, in a React Native app:

```
<TextInput
 style = {styles.input}
 placeholder = 'Room...'
 onChange = {setRoom}
 value = {room} 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, after reading documentation about <TextInput>, it was the problem : the solution was as described here : https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput

Comment: Yes, that's the short version with the {setRoom} instead of the arrow function (no difference in behavior and looks more neat). Glad you could find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to talk with hooks like say the documentation:

```js
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              placeholder='Room...'
              onChangeText={setRoom}
              value={room}
              />
```

Comment: It has same answer up above, so it is unfair to ask, someone respond and then you post response to your own question bast on someone else answer.